# REST Post WS with File param : 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

This is my WS that i try to test with Advanced REST client (Chrome plugin) :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Schema/myWS")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]FileStream file)
{ 
     log.info("blah");
}
```

When i don't join a file, i'm able reach the WS.
But as soon as i join a file, i get a 500: Internal Server Error.

I've tried with the application/json, multipart/form-data, i can always reach my WS, but never when i join a file...
Any idea?

Edit :

I've tried with an HTML/js file to post my file (instead of chrome plugin), same result, if i don't join a file, i can reach my WS, if i join a file -> 500 error :

```
<body>
   <input id="filePicker" type="file" name="Package" />
   <a onclick="upload();">send!</a>
</body>



<script type="text/javascript">
function upload() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:52087/api/Schema/convertDwgEnJson');
  request.send(filePicker.files[0]);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Problem is not in the WS code, when i set a breakpoint to the "log.info" for example, it's never fired, the code is not reached

Comment: dude do you think this much of code is sufficient to find the problem ?

Comment: nope -_- , generally `Internal Server Error.` is due to problem on server side, like missing parameter or unexpected exception etc

Comment: Yes but it doesn't reach the code anyway, so it cannot be the problem, i must miss something in the WS declaration, or don't use chrome plugin as i should

Comment: ok tell me what your WS exact does ? does it upload file ?

Comment: It's supposed to analyse the file, extract some things, and return a Json

Comment: A 500 error is usually accompanied by an exception message, what's the exception?

Comment: Got that in console : "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details".